# How do I get the Aurelia-cli to provide a stack trace on a gulp plugin error?

Tags: aurelia

To any Aurelia CLI pros out there:

I've successfully got karma code coverage setup and mapping the bundled output back to my typescript sources, but the karma plugin is throwing an error when generating the output. See here:

```
{ uid: 0,
  name: 'unit',
  branch: false,
  error: 
   { [TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null]
     domain: 
      Domain {
        domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        members: [] },
     domainThrown: true },
  duration: [ 1, 611956616 ],
  time: 1474556751202 }
{ [TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null]
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: {},
     _eventsCount: 0,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] },
  domainThrown: true }
```

How do I tell the CLI to give me the stack trace so that I can go and fix the issue in the plugin?

Here is a project that demonstrates the problem:
https://github.com/Roustalski/aurelia-typescript-coverage

Follow the instructions in the README.

Comment: You can modify the gulp tasks yourself. Just change the tasks to contain a catch that logs out the stack trace

Comment: I'm in the same situation, it appears to be related to generating the detail pages

Answer (score 0):

You can actually step through CLI: [How to debug Aurelia CLI](https://github.com/aurelia-contrib/aurelia-getting-started/blob/master/guides/how-to-debug-cli.md)

TL:DR Using vscode you can setup launch target for node and execute cli with debugger attached.